# Mongoose create multiple Connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm following [Mongoose Connection Docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#multiple_connections) to create multiple Databases Connections on express app. When i import my schema scoped to a connection i can't use models functions such like .find || .findOne etc.. and i get the next error

> UserSchema.find is not a function

Is there something that i miss to add or is something i'm making wrong ??

Here is Schema code:

models/user.js

```
const { Schema } = require('mongoose');

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: String},
    lastname: { type: String}
});

module.exports = UserSchema;
```

And then i create the connection with the model scooped to it.

databases/connection_1.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Keys } = require('../keys');

const conn = mongoose.createConnection(
    `mongodb://${Keys.DatabaseUser}:${Keys.DatabasePassword}@${Keys.DatabaseHost}/${Keys.DatabaseShema}`
    , { 
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useCreateIndex: true,
        useFindAndModify: true
    });

    conn.model('User', require('../models/user'), 'Users')

module.exports = conn;
```

But when i try to use my Schema to fetch the data of the Database i get next error:

> UserSchema.find is not a function

routes/index.js

```
const app = require('express').Router();
const UserSchema = require('../models/user');

app.get('/index', async (req,res) => {
    console.log(await UserSchema.find({name: 'Jhon Doe'}))
})

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: It was a typing error i did when i created the post. The error still happens

Comment: You cannot call find on a schema, because it's... a schema. A blueprint that models are built upon. You need to export a model with desired connection.